# MSMQ Public Queues Cannot see public queue that I created

Tags: queue, message-queue, messaging, msmq

We have installed MSMQ on Win2019 server
In Computer Management > Message Queuing, when I click on Public Queues, it gives me the error

I went ahead and create a "New Public Queue" and named it "Test1"
It says "The object was successfully created. However Active Directory Domain services replication delays may prevent you from seeing it now. Wait several minutes and then click 'Refresh' to see the object."

Even after I waited for hours, I still don't see the queue.

I clicked "Refresh", and I got "Not all public queues can be displayed. Only public queues cached locally can be displayed."

But if I create another "New Public Queue" with the same name "Test1", it says "test1 cannot be created. Error: A queue with the same path name already exists."

How can I see the Public Queues ?

Thank you